Перебрать все комбинации элементов без повторения
Есть список ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д"].
Нужно перебрать все комбинации этих элементов,
при условии, что элемент не может повторятся в одной
из комбинаций (это не взломщик паролей).
alf = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д']

while True:
    slovo = ' '
    for i in range(len(alf)):
        slovo += str(alf[i])
print(slovo)

а потом застрял.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Смотря что вы называете комбинациями...  Вероятно, itertools.combinations подойдёт. Или самостоятельно нужно алгоритм разработать?

сейчас проверю. может itertools.combinations сработает

А что если мне надо просто переставленные символы в переменной / списке? Он не даёт результат если длинна комбинации равна длине списка.

А что если ... -  нужно точно объяснить, что требуется, и привести пример.

Ну, например, так:
import itertools

my_list = ["а", "б", "в", "г", "д"]
combinations = list(itertools.permutations(my_list, len(my_list)))

for combination in combinations:
    print(combination)


Спасибо. :-)   Полезно очень.

На будущее: совершенно не нужно давать длинные имена счетчикам циклов (даже если они не вложенные). Это ведет к опечаткам и трудно отлавливаемым ошибкам.

Возможно вас удивит моё название convert_UTF8_Float_or_Int(text)
